# How can i use multimatrix in a loop in OpenSCAD?

Tags: openscad

i wish to chain cubes end to end inside a loop, so that i can construct a spiral made of cubes only using dynamic rules of how they are added together rather than a parametric equation. i.e. translate 1, tilt 20', rotate-z 10'... would make a 3d spirograph.

Here is an example file using openscad recursion (which memory-crashes very fast compared to openscad loops) i wish to do the same using a loop? i am confused.

```
levels = 50; // number of levels for the recursion

len = 100; // length of the first segment
thickness = 5; // thickness of the first segment

// the identity matrix
identity = [ [ 1, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 1, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 1, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 1 ] ];

// random generator
function rnd(s, e) = rands(s, e, 1)[0];

// generate 4x4 translation matrix
function mt(x, y) = [ [ 1, 0, 0, x ], [ 0, 1, 0, y ], [ 0, 0, 1, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 1 ] ];

// generate 4x4 rotation matrix around Z axis
function mr(a) = [ [ cos(a), -sin(a), 0, 0 ], [ sin(a), cos(a), 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 1, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 1 ] ];

module tree(length, thickness, count, m = identity) {
    color([0, 1 - (0.8 / levels * count), 0])
        multmatrix(m)
            cube([thickness, length, thickness]);

    if (count > 0) {
        tree( length, thickness, count - 1, m * mt(0, length) * mr(31.4159));

    }
}

tree(len, thickness, levels);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can generate the list of matrices in a recursive function first 
and use the result in a for() module to generate the actual geometry.

```
// the identity matrix 
identity = [ [ 1, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 1, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 1, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 1 ] ]; 

// generate 4x4 rotation matrix around Z axis 
function mr(a) = [ [ cos(a), -sin(a), 0, 0 ], [ sin(a), cos(a), 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 1, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 1 ] ]; 

// generate 4x4 translation matrix 
function mt(x, y) = [ [ 1, 0, 0, x ], [ 0, 1, 0, y ], [ 0, 0, 1, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 1 ] ]; 

function matrices(i = 10, m = identity, ret = []) = i >= 0 
        ? matrices(i - 1, m * mt(0, 10) * mr(20), concat(ret, [ m ])) 
        : ret; 

for (m = matrices(17)) 
  multmatrix(m) 
    cube([5, 10, 5]);
```

with help form Torsten Paul.